# issue in Zend_Frame_ Select box validation in ajax call

Tags: zend-framework

i have created a country select box as
$country= new Zend_Form_Element_Select('country'); 
in my user registration form ..
While selecting an country an ajax call is send and getting the state list 
by creating another select box 
$state= new Zend_Form_Element_Select('state'); 
in another action say stateAction()

Problem is that when i tried to validate registration form in the POST action
i cant retrieve the value from  state 
$form = new Users_Form_Register();
eg as $userObjectDetails->statename=$form->getValue('state');

as a solution i added tried to added a dummy variable $state in  Users_Form_Register();
add addElement($state),unfortunately during  value is loaded by ajax call the state list issue occure during validation of the form

please suggest a solution for the above
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try validating with javascript. jQuery has [a nice validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) that lets you attach the validator to the form ID and define the rules you want to validate.